# Fluent-ffmpeg : Output with label 'screen0' doesnot exist in any diferent filter graph, or was already used elsewhere

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to take video frame by frame using fluent-ffmpeg, to create video masking and some kin of like experiment video editor. But when I do that by `screenshots` it says `ffmpeg exited with code 1: Output with label 'screen0' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.`

Here example array that I use for producing timestamps. `["0.019528","0.05226","0.102188","0.13635","0.152138","0.186013","0.236149" ...]`

```js
// read json file that contains timestaps, array
fs.readFile(`${config.videoProc}/timestamp/1.json`, 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw new Error(err.message);
  const timestamp = JSON.parse(data);
  // screenshot happens here
  // loop till there is nothing on array...
  function takeFrame() {
    command.input(`${config.publicPath}/static/video/1.mp4`)
      .on('error', error => console.log(error.message))
      .on('end', () => {
        if (timestamp.length > 0) {
          // screenshot again ...
          takeFrame();
        } else {
          console.log('Process ended');
        }
      })
      .noAudio()
      .screenshots({
        timestamps: timestamp.splice(0, 100),
        filename: '%i.png',
        folder: '../video/img',
        size: '320x240',
      });
  }
  // call the function
  takeFrame();
});
```

My expected result are, I can genereta all the 600 screenshot. on one video. but the actual result is this error `ffmpeg exited with code 1: Output with label 'screen0' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere` and only 100 screen generated.

**[UPDATE]**

using `-filter_complex` as mentioned in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/921810/ffmpeg-syntax-label-not-found-error) doenst work.

```js
ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

**[UPDATE]**

command line arg :

```
ffmpeg -ss 0.019528 -i D:\Latihan\video-cms-core\public/static/video/1.mp4 -y -filter_complex scale=w=320:h=240[size0];[size0]split=1[screen0] -an -vframes 1 -map [screen0] ..\video\img\1.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that using

`ffmpeg().input(path)` and `ffmpeg(path)` behave differently. Thats make duplicate on input frames. first command keeping old input frames and add it, and second command doesnt. so the second command works perfectly.

Thanks.

Working code :

```js
  function takeFrame() {
   // notice that I inisitae this new ffmpeg, not using const command = new ffmpeg() 
    const screenshots = new ffmpeg(`${config.publicPath}/static/video/1.mp4`)
      .on('error', error => console.log(error.message))
      .on('end', () => {
        if (timestamp.length > 0) {
          // screenshot again ...
          takeFrame();
        } else {
          console.log('Process ended');
        }
      })
      .noAudio()
      .screenshots({
        timestamps: timestamp.splice(0, 100),
        filename: '%i.png',
        folder: '../video/img',
        size: '320x240',
      });
  }
  // call the function
  takeFrame();
});
```